# Debug time issue

Tags: c++

I created a data bag structure. I read the text of a file and convert to lexicographical order. In order to do this I have to convert two string to lower case to compare them(One for the current node and one for the node that is next to it). But my problem is when I have big text files, it has to keep converting the string to lower case for each node I insert and sometimes it takes a long time to process. I was wondering if there are any ways better ways of adjusting this so I can increase the performance time.

```
void insert(string v)
{
    if(head == NULL){ //empty list
        head = new BagNode;
        head->dataValue = v;
        //head->dataCount = 0;
        head->next = NULL;

    }
    else
    {
            BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
            n->dataValue = v;
            BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
            //current = head;
            n->dataCount = 0;
                if(!isBefore(current->dataValue, v))        //new head
                {
                    n->next = head;
                    head = n;
                }
                else{           //mid and tail insert
                    while(current->next && isBefore(current->next->dataValue,v))
                    {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    n->next = current->next;
                    current->next = n;

                }   
         }      
    }
```

Compare the two nodes

```
 bool isBefore(string a, string b) 
 {
      transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ::tolower);
      transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), ::tolower);
        if(a == b) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Keep in a node both original and converted string. The first for application use, the second for comparisons only.  Do the same for inserting: convert once, look for the correct place, and insert original and converted. You will, as usual, trade space for time.

Comment: `NULL` is for C99. Use `nullptr` in C++11. BTW you should use C++ [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) & [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: Also compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) and use the debugger (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Fyi, an attribute of using a linked list for your container is complexity O(N) per search (which you're doing with each insertion). That equates to O(N^2) to perform N insertions. *That* will be the dominant trait that hinders performance in your bag.  Use a different data structure (such as a tree, ideally a *balanced* tree).

Answer (score 0):

to debugging a program in C or C++ using g++ or gcc

1) `gcc/g++ -g myprogram.c/myprogram.cpp`

the result will be  a.out

2) `gdb a.out`

I hope it help you!

Comment: This is a comment (quite similar to mine's) not an answer